# wallet-cli generated wallet prompts "invalid password" when used in wallet-rpc

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc

I run a small Wallet-RPC Server on a linux machine (k3s cluster on a raspberry pi 5 running rpi os lite). When I generate a new wallet on my Mac (m1 sonoma) [using monero-wallet-cli](https://www.monero.how/tutorial-how-to-create-a-command-line-monero-wallet) and copying it onto the wallet dir on the server, the wallet rpc always prompts me: "Invalid password".

I started the wallet rpc service with "--wallet-dir" instead of "--wallet-file" and [created a new wallet using curl](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#create_wallet) on the rpc endpoint and that wallet works totally fine on the rpc server. When copying the wallet that works on the rpc server back to my mac, again I cannot open it ("Invalid password").

Both wallets work perfectly fine on each of the machines but cannot opened on the other. The systems are both AARCH64 architectures (apple silicone and the raspberry pi 5) and both are running the latest Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.2.2-release).

Are there known limitations to this that I just wasn't aware of or am I just doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance to anyone taking the time to help me out <3